# Designing reliable agent based push module to push data from one boundary to other

Tags: c#, .net, azure, .net-6.0, system-design

**Problem statement:** Design a module that can be consumed by the customers to ***push data (metadata of varying entity. e.g. Product, Car and similar POJO) from their boundary to our boundary***. The data is from the hot path and it may not be fetched again. This *requirement is very much like high performance log agent which push log from the service to external storage except we are pushing metadata of different entities in this case.*

**Constraints :** It should have limited impact on customer's hot path. External resources like Queue shouldn't be into the Customer's boundary.

**Why Agent based module?** : The idea is that agent will persist the data locally and can re-try sending the data in case of failures. I may use a Queue in our boundary but the Customer Service may fail to push the data to the Queue resulting in loss of data.

Here's how the design would look like.

1. Service A is in the Customer's boundary. Agent can reside in the Service A of the Customer from where it would push the data to our Queue.
2. The Queue is an optional resource added in our boundary. We have a single Service that consumes the message being pushed from the agent and we may consume the message directly bypassing the Queue.
3. The agent persists the data locally in the Customer's VM and can push the data over a period of time.

[image: Agent based design]

**Question :** *Can we use Azure Monitor Agent for the purpose of pushing metadata through a rest API? Is there any existing agent that can be re-used?* Basically I'm looking for a way to store metadata in a file system and then push it through rest API.

Comment: The questions you answer tend to be about MS Azure configuration, pricing, infrastructure, and other cloud-related issues, instead of being practical programming problems. StackOverflow is meant to discuss only programming questions. [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
for more details. Please post your non-programming question on other platforms such as [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/)
, and [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/tags/133/azure)
for immediate help. Thanks!

Comment: @NaveenSharma How is this Cloud specific issue? The question is more around looking for a design that can read from disk and push it to external partner.
Here's one such library that I came across
https://github.com/i-e-b/DiskQueue

Comment: Great that you found something toward it, I Hope the community will have a look at this with more points!